# Can android studio in Ubuntu point to SDK of another android studio in Windows 7?

Tags: ubuntu, sdk, android-studio

I had android studio in windows 7 that had a complete SDK.As it was too slow I installed Ubuntu on the laptop beside of windows and installed another android studio on Ubuntu.

Now Can I use SDK in android studio in windows for android studio in Ubuntu for saving time and space?